# Audiokit 4.5 playgrounds opening, building, but no sound

Tags: audiokit

In the past I've got previous versions of the playgrounds to work. However I can't get the new 2 day old version (4.5.0) from GitHub to work.

I downloaded the zip file from https://audiokit.io/downloads/ page.
I expanded the zip. 
I launched Xcode by clicking on the AudioKitPlaygrounds.xcodeproj file.
I go to the Hello World tutorial.
I click on run button and it builds successful.
No errors, nothing in console, no yellow or red build or runtime errors - but no sound. Also no sound in the handful of other playgrounds I spot tested.

I search on the internet - and found an answer saying to add this setting, but it had no effect.
AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true

The volume is definitely on. I have got the ROMPlayer working as a separate project using cocoa pods. But not the playgrounds. Any help much appreciated. Thanks Domc

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved partly the issue - although not clear to me why this works - answer posted in case it's helpful for others.

Having tried downloading various versions, none of which worked, I tried to build many times. I noticed it seemed to be getting stuck on "Running ...." with spinning dial at top.

Researching this led me to a post re another playground with similar problem that said to untick and tick the links to the frameworks on the individual frameworks pages which I did.

A few minutes later I tried running again and I got sound! However if I select the table of contents the whole program crashes x-code and on reload you have to 'reconnect' the frameworks by ticking and unticking. [Probably this shouldn't be happening]

Comment: My experience is that the playgrounds work for 4-5 playgrounds and then you'll get Xcode to crash.  This is better than Xcode 9 which would only run half the time.  I have found that you can met Xcode more stable by manually stop the playground you are on before switching to a new one.  I didn't know this framework trick but I wonder if its a red herring.